# Best way to store a variable size list in Azure Storage Table

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage

I need to store a list of variable size in Azure Table Storage. Let's say it's a list GUIDs and that it can be as large as tens of thousands of GUIDs per list (like, the IDs of posts authored by an user).

I'm thinking about 2 approaches here:

1. Serialize the list in an efficient binary format (like protobuf) and store the result in a blob

   - Pros: I can fetch the complete list in a single operation
   - Cons: I need to manage the entire list in-memory even to access a range or a single item!
2. Store the list in a table, with the list ID being the partition key and each GUID being the row key

   - Pros: I can access each GUID randomly and I can "paginate" range queries (take 20, then take 20 with RK > last item from previous range...)
   - Cons: Fetching requires full partition scan, which I believe is as bad a crossing the streams

Basically, I'm looking for confirmation on the cons of option 2: is partition scan so bad, even if I limit the number of entities retrieved (.Take(x)) and I optionally set a constraint on the RK?

Also, other ways to efficiently store such a list in Azure Tables would be welcome, even though I think the options are limited!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that if you need to get all the posts you'll need to scan the entire partition. However, if you can store something meaningful in the RowKey, then you won't need to fetch all the posts every time. For example, if you typically show the latest posts, you can make the RowKey descending by date, and then most of the time you'll only need to get the first few rows.

Comment: Indeed, it all comes down to the kind of queries you have to perform (as usual in NoSQL). Still, do you know if fetching the first x rows of a partition is more efficient than a full partition scan? In other words, does it have to scan the full partition to find the first 20 rows, or does the indexing directly return the x rows only? (I guess that would be a question for the guys at MS implementing Table Storage!)

Comment: The data is indexed by row key, so fetching by a range of row keys is definitely better than fetching the entire partition.

Comment: I mean the data inside a partition.